# SSL Protocol Error, in Android/Cordova Only On WIFI

Tags: cordova, vue.js, vue-resource

I have an app built with Cordova.
I use vue.js, and in doing any get/post with vue-resource I get the following error:

```
 ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

Here is the odd thing:
1) it works in browser normally
2) it works in app, on 3g/4g, but gets the error in WIFI only.

Comment: here is the code, but its really in ALL post/get, and only on wifi:     this.`$http.post( 'https://domain.com/api/auth/signin', credentials, function( data ) {
        self.items = data;
        if(data.meta.token){
          localStorage.setItem('jwt-token',data.meta.token);
          localStorage.setItem('auth','true');
          router.go('/');
        }
      });`

Comment: What was the fix?

Comment: sorry, its a long time ago, as I recall, I rebuilt it from scratch